# B2C custom policy invitation link expiry custom error message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have setup azure b2c custom policy for inivation flow, using this sample https://github.com/mrochon/b2csamples, it's working fine, but when the inivation link gets expired, and user opens that it shows error page with

"AADB2C90017: The client assertion provided in the request is invalid: 'client_secret' was used as the verification key"

I want to change the error message so user can know that link is expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set a [custom error page UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#content-definition-ids) and Use CSS to hide the default error message.

[Using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) parse the default error message when it contains "AADB2C90017", then show a custom error message.

There are some samples which explains [how to enable java script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples)